# SQL to Return missing Row

Tags: sql

I have one Scenario where I need to find missing records in Table using SQL - without using Cursor, Views, SP.

- For a particular CustID initial Start_Date will be 19000101 and End_date will be any random date.
- Then for next Record for the same CustID will have its Start_Date as End_Date (of previous Record) + 1.
- Its End_Date again will be any random date.
- And so on….
- For Last record of same CustID its end Date will be 99991231.

Following population of data will explain it better.

```
CustID  Start_Date  End_Date
1   19000101    20121231
1   20130101    20130831
1   20130901    20140321
1   20140321    99991231
```

Basically I am trying to populate data like in SCD2 scenario.

Now I want to find missing record (or CustID).

Like below we don’t have record with `CustID = 4` with `Start_Date = 20120606` and `End_Date = 20140101`

```
CustID  Start_Date  End_Date
4   19000101    20120605
4   20140102    99991231
```

Code for Creating Table

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
  CustID int,
  Start_Date int,
  End_Date int
)

INSERT INTO TestTable values (1,19000101,20121231)
INSERT INTO TestTable values (1,20130101,20130831)
INSERT INTO TestTable values (1,20130901,20140321)
INSERT INTO TestTable values (1,20140321,99991231)

INSERT INTO TestTable values (2,19000101,99991213)

INSERT INTO TestTable values (3,19000101,20140202)
INSERT INTO TestTable values (3,20140203,99991231)
INSERT INTO TestTable values (4,19000101,20120605)
--INSERT INTO TestTable values (4,20120606,20140101)   --Missing Value
INSERT INTO TestTable values (4,20140102,99991231)
```

Now SQL should return `CustID = 4` as its has missing Value.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Btw, storing dates as integers makes the problem harder than it would need to be. Any particular reason you're doing so?

Answer (score 2):

My idea is based on this logic. Lets assume 19000101 as 1 and 99991231 as 10. Now for all IDs, if you subtract the End_date - start_date and add them up, the total sum must be equal to 9 (10 - 1). You can do the same here

```
SELECT ID, SUM(END_DATE - START_DATE) as total from TABLE group by ID where total < (MAX_END_DATE - MIN_START_DATE)
```

You might want to find the command in your SQL that gives the number of days between 2 days and use that in the SUM part.

Lets take the following example

```
1 1900 2003
1 2003 9999
2 1900 2222
2 2222 9977
3 1900 9999
```

The query will be executed as follows

```
1 (2003 - 1900) + (9999 - 2003) = 1 8098
2 (2222 - 1900) + (9977 - 2222) = 2 9077
3 (9999 - 1900) = 3 8098
```

The where clause will eliminate 1 and 3 giving you only 2, which is what you want.

Comment: Updated with an example @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: The end doesn't equal the start however, so you will be left with the number of results.  For instance you might have rows (1900-2002,2003-2004,2005-9999) which would be complete and give you 8097, or one complete row with (1900-9999) which gives you 8099.

Comment: In that case you would use SUM(END - START) - COUNT(*) -1

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the CustID then this will do

```
SELECT t1.CustID
FROM TestTable t1
LEFT JOIN TestTable t2
ON DATEADD(D, 1, t1.Start_Date) = t2.Start_Date
WHERE t2.CustID IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.CustID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need rows if the one of the following conditions is met:

1. Not a final row (99991231) and no matching next row
2. Not a start row (19000101) and no matching previous row

You can left join to the same table to find previous and next rows and filter the results where you don't find a row by checking the column values for null:

```
SELECT t1.CustID, t1.StartDate, t1.EndDate
FROM TestTable t1
LEFT JOIN TestTable tPrevious on tPrevious.CustID = t1.CustID
    and tPrevious.EndDate = t1.StartDate - 1
LEFT JOIN TestTable tNext on tNext.CustID = t1.CustID
    and tNext.StartDate = t1.EndDate + 1
WHERE (t1.EndDate <> 99991231 and tNext.CustID is null) -- no following
    or (t1.StartDate <> 19000101 and tPrevious.CustID is null) -- no previous
```